# What does 何+(counter)+も+volitional mean? e.g. 何機も買おう

Tags: grammar, counters, particle-も, volitional-form

I found this sentence as an answer to the question: "What are some of the symbols of Japan's wealth?"

> 次期主力戦闘機を何機も買おうとしていること

I'm not sure whether it means they're buying a lot of next-generation fighters, or none at all.

I think it's a bunkei I have yet to learn, and I can't find it in the textbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no relation here.  It is simply `何機も` followed by the form `〜（よ）うとする`.  The `何機も` corresponds to the combat planes because planes are counted with `機`.  The `何 + counter + も` pattern just means "several" or an undetermined amount of that thing.  For example

> - 食堂に生徒が何人もいます　→　There are several / There are a number of students in the cafeteria.

So your first translation is correct.  "They will try/intend to purchase several combat planes next." (+ `こと` to answer the question).

Answer (score 2):

It's not as apparent in  [ 食堂に生徒が何人もいます ]　  but

in   [ 次期主力戦闘機を何機も買おうとしていること ]

the implication is (as you said) that they're buying a lot of next-generation fighters  -- the suggestion of "too many"  or "many".

The "too many" sense is clear in the follwoing examples.

- そんなに何度も何度も 言わないで分かってるから　　　無残にも悲しい顔を ひとつすることもなくて 溶けて消えてゆく 染まって色づいてく綺麗な言葉ほど歪んでいて「もうほっといて ...

> 夜､何度もトイレに起きる男は早死にする!?　　　　　　 東洋経済オンライン-2016/08/30
>
> 夜間、何度もトイレに起きる男性が多いようですね。 統計によると日本人男性の場合、50歳以上になると、夜中に1回以上トイレに起きる人が半分以上を占めるとされます。さらに70歳以上では、1回以上トイレに起きる人が大半を占めるそうです ...