# Use of も with counter

Tags: grammar, counters, particle-も, intonation

The writer is complaining that men are useless at cooking. They burn pans, they make more mess than is necessary and:

> ...、何枚も皿をつかう、...

I can't fully understand this construction. I know the essence is that men use too many plates but that's all I can understand.

In particular I don't know what も is doing. I'm not sure if this is a question, a rhetorical question or a statement. Nor am I sure of the intonation (i.e. rising at the end or not).

In English we might say "and how many plates do they use". Depending on the intonation this could be a plain question or a rhetorical question where we simply mean that they use too many plates. I'm guessing the Japanese is this latter usage but I have no idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does 何(+counter)+も+volitional mean? e.g. 何機も買おう](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12549/what-does-%e4%bd%95counter%e3%82%82volitional-mean-e-g-%e4%bd%95%e6%a9%9f%e3%82%82%e8%b2%b7%e3%81%8a%e3%81%86)

Comment: I request that this be left open.  That old question was not really answered correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This 「も」 expresses the speaker's surprise or exclamation about the (large) quantity or (high) frequency that is being discussed.  It is used when the quantity or frequency ***exceeds*** one's expectations.

> 「[何]{なん} + Counter + も」 = "***so*** many (noun)"
>
> 「Actual Number + Counter + も」 = "(number) + (noun) + to one's surprise"

「[何枚]{なんまい}も[皿]{さら}をつかう」, therefore, means:

> "(men) use ***so*** many plates (than you would expect) while cooking"

This is an exclamatory statement, and not a question or rhetorical question.

As for the pronunciation, you ***do not*** use a rising intonation.  **If anything, we would usually enunciate the 「なん」 part and the actual number part respectively**.

For reference, see definition #5 in [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%82-644757#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89):

Comment: I agree overall with your answer, except for the emphasis on "exceed's one expectations" which seems overly constraining for the definition.  e.g. 当然ですが、上手になるためなん回も練習しなきゃ