# Difference between the patterns 何 + COUNTER + か and 何 + COUNTER + も

Tags: grammar, particle-も, particle-か, pattern

> 私は今年**何度か**海外に行きました。 [[SOURCE]](https://nihongomaster.com/japanese/dictionary/word/17807/nandoka)
>
> > I have been abroad several times this year.
>
> 北海道へ**何度も**行った
>
> > I have been to Hokkaido many times.

> 本を**何冊も**読む。[[SOURCE]](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/11810399)
>
> > I read several books.
>
> 本を**何冊か**買いました。
>
> > I bought some books.

> **何杯か**飲んだ後で [[SOURCE]](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%BD%95%E6%9D%AF%E3%81%8B)
>
> > After a couple of drinks
>
> **何杯も**お茶を飲む [[SOURCE]](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%BD%95%E6%9D%AF%E3%82%82)
>
> > Drink countless coups of tea
>
> 昔は、私がもっともっと若い時は、1日に**何杯も**コーヒーを飲んでいました [[SOURCE]](https://www.lingq.com/en/lesson/27hao-kinayin-mimonohananikohinisha-t-7766164/?term=%E4%BD%95%20%E6%9D%AF)
>
> > (DeepL) In the past, when I was much younger, I used to drink several cups of coffee a day.

I cannot see any difference other than the one with も being emphatic.

---

[image: img1]

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36449/use-of-%e3%82%82-with-counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't there a big difference between *some* and *many*?

- **何 + COUNTER + か**: some; several; a few; a couple of
- **何 + COUNTER + も**: many; a lot of; a number of
  <sub>(But "countless" is usually too strong)</sub>

Your second link contains an incorrect translation. 本を何冊も読む means "to read many books" rather than "to read several books". 何杯もコーヒーを飲む is "to drink many cups of coffee", and [DeepL says so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J25Xw.png), too.

Comment: My current understanding is that both **何 + COUNTER + か** and **何 + COUNTER + も** refer to an indefinite amount of something specified by the counter, but the latter emphasizes the amount. Accordingly,  expressions such as *some*, *a few*, *a couple* go with the former while *many*, *several*, *a lot of*, *a number of* with the latter. By the way,  DeepL translates 「1日に何杯もコーヒーを飲んでいました」 as "I was drinking several cups of coffee a day" for me atleast.

Comment: @Nameless Looks like adding "私がもっともっと若い時は" somehow changes the translation of 何杯も. As always, it's hard to imagine what deep learning-based AI is doing, but it sometimes makes terrible mistakes that appear to be plausible...

Comment: I see. Is the statement "Both 何 + COUNTER + か and 何 + COUNTER + も refer to an indefinite amount of something specified by the counter, but the latter emphasizes the amount" correct though? I've taken *several* to mean *a lot  of* instead of *some*,  but for the rest of expressions, it seems to be correct.

Comment: *Several* means "more than two but fewer than many; some" according to [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/several). "Emphasizes the amount" may not be wrong but it sounds too vague to me...