# How to use the particle も

Tags: particle-も

I have been studying japanese for some time now (my level floating somewhere between beginner and intermediate), and the particle も has confused me.

I already know it works kind of like "too" or "also"
Ex: 私も。「わたしも」== "Me too"

However, I've seen sentences where this meaning of "too" isn't present

Ex:
雨はもう3日「も」降っています

(It's been raining for nearly three days now)

Can someone give me a general overview of what も can represent, and in what contexts the meaning of it will change. Thank you.

Comment: There are a number of good web sources for this info already, such as https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/particle-mo/ or https://maggiesensei.com/2013/10/08/japanese-particle-%E3%82%82mo-to-emphasize-the-number-%E3%80%8C%E4%B8%80%E2%98%85%E3%82%82%E3%80%8D/ .  Is there something in particular you feel they don't adequately explain?  (in particular, you might want to look at the "quantity + も" explanation under Tofugu's article.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is "nearly 3 days" your own translation? I'd have read this as "as many as 3 days". I may of course be wrong. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36449/use-of-%e3%82%82-with-counter/36450#36450

Answer (score 1):

も is often glossed as "also, too, even".

Looking again at your sample sentence:

> 雨【あめ】はもう[3日]{みっか}**[も]{●}**降【ふ】っています

The も is used here as an intensifier, emphasizing that it's been **three days**.  It might help to think of this more like:

> It's already been raining for three days, **even**!