# What does this mean in context? [幾本も幾本も]

Tags: words, counters, particle-も

From 銀河鉄道の夜（宮沢賢治）

> 二人がその白い道を 、 肩をならべて行きますと 、 二人の影は 、 ちょうど四方に窓のある部屋 の中の 、 二本の柱の影のように 、 また二つの車輪の輻のように幾本も幾本も四方へ出るのでした.

1. What does 幾本も幾本も mean exactly and how is it used?
2. How is it pronounced? Is it いくほん？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern Japanese one would say 何本も何本も.

- 幾 is indeed pronounced いく.
- The 本 (ほん) following it just appears because the 柱 are counted with 本.
- The doubling is for emphasis.

> 幾本も
> pole after pole
>
> 幾本も幾本も
> pole after pole after pole

Also see

- [What is the meaning of 幾里?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32572/1628)
- [What's the difference between 何【なん】 and 幾【いく】 when referring to amounts?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12639/1628)
- [What does 何+(counter)+も+volitional mean? e.g. 何機も買おう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12549/1628)

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Easier than I expected. Thank you!